# Как вынести плагины в глобальную область видимости в webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Пытаюсь вынести плагины в глобальную область видимости через providePlugin, но не получается. В index.js все выводит, но если обращаюсь к плагинам из других файлов, то не видит плагины.

```
// index.js 
console.log($) - это видит
import './item.js';

// item.js 
console.log($) - это уже не видит
```

CONFIG

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
const isProd = !isDev

const plugins = () => {
    const base = [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].bundle.css',
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            'window.Swiper': 'swiper',
            Swiper: 'swiper',
        }),
    ]

    return base;
}

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: ["./js/index.js", "./scss/template.scss"],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            name: 'vendor'
        }
    },
    devtool: isDev ? 'source-map' : false,
    plugins: plugins(),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, "./scss"),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {},
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            url: false,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                            postcssOptions: {
                                config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'postcss.config.js'),
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
```